# Why return action does not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData.Model = new Model();
        return Action1();
    }

    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When I called the index action, it will call action1 method, and then call the index action again. Anyone knows why is this behaving this way?

I know we can use RedirectToAction("Action1") to solve this, but I'm just curious the reason behind this behaviour. Thanks heaps.

RWendi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not call the `Index` action again. Because the action you invoked at the first time was `Index` the method `View()` will return the view corresponding to `Index`. That is why you see the view for `Index`.

Comment: Makes sense, but then it should've called the Action1 method again, but it didn't. Do you know why is that?

Comment: @RWendi: No, it only returns the `view` that the `Index` action corresponds. If what you are saying was true. Then returning a `View()` from an action would recursively call that method. Isn't it? Actually, **when you call another action from an action No new request is made. Which is not true in case of `RedirectToAction` where new request is made.** For a proof, check the URL in the browser in two cases.